# Что значит OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

В чём смысл установки `@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` и `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` в нижеследующем скрипте?

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;

USE `events`;

/* Alter table in target */
ALTER TABLE `eventlog` ENGINE=InnoDB; 
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
```

Как я понимаю, выражение `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` отключает проверку внешних ключей. А для чего необходимо `OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`? Это просто переменная, которая временно хранит значение глобальной переменной `@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Источник: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-faq.html

> Determines whether the server should check that a referenced table
>   exists when defining a foreign key. Due to potential circular
>   references, this check must be turned off for the duration of the
>   import, to permit defining foreign keys

Настройка показывает, должен ли сервер проверять факт существования целевой таблицы при создании ключа.